# How do I get 3 integer input on the same line and store it as 3 different variables?

Tags: c++

I need to do something like this

```
int num1, num2, num3;
```

User Input: (num1) (blank space or tab) (num2) (blank space or tab) (num3) (blank space or tab)

(blank space or tab) can be " " or \t

```
cout << num1 << num2 << num3;
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;
```

Comment: Doesn't this require that I press enter before each number?

Comment: No, but you will have to press enter after you enter the third number (probably).