# How can I input multiple variables on the same line C++

Tags: c++

So I am trying to input multiple variables on the same line and have it call a function and parse some of the variables to a function it will call. For example the user will enter something like

```
COMMAND <integer>
```

I have tried using scanf however when it does work it doesn't seem to recognize the variable I passed. I am certain I am just making a silly mistake but can someone please help me? I wrote a simple program to try to test passing variables like this which I have included below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

string derp(int test) {
    cout << "and here " + test << endl;
    return "derp " + test;
}


void main() {
    char command[20];
    int *bla(0);
    scanf("%s %u", &command[0], &bla );
    if (strcmp(command, "derp") == 0) {
        cout << "works here" << endl;
        cout << derp(*bla);
    }
}
```

Comment: try scanf("%s %u", command, &bla );

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get 3 integer input on the same line and store it as 3 different variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437637/how-do-i-get-3-integer-input-on-the-same-line-and-store-it-as-3-different-variab)

Comment: **int *bla** --> **int bla**, and maybe **unsigned int bla** since your are scanfing it with **%u**

Comment: Use `std::getline()` to read the line of text, construct a `std::istringstream`, and parse it using `operator>>`, or by manually chewing on the string. That's how it's done in C++. `scanf()`, at all, is a C library function. Ancient history.

Comment: `"and here " << test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change: `int *bla(0);` from being a pointer to an actual variable: `int bla(0);`

Same goes for output: `cout << derp(*bla);` to `cout << derp(bla);` (no longer need dereferencing on bla).

Also, you can't output a sum of a C-string + an int, it's not concatenation. Use chained output:

`cout << "and here " + test << endl;` should be `cout << "and here " << test << endl;`

and

`return "derp " + test;` should be fixed for the same reason.

**Fixed version:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

string derp(int test) {
    cout << "and here " << test << endl;
    return std::string("derp ") + to_string(test);
}


void main() {
    char command[20];
    int bla(0);
    scanf("%s %u", &command[0], &bla);
    if (strcmp(command, "derp") == 0) {
        cout << "works here" << endl;
        cout << derp(bla);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, like I said I felt like it was something silly that I just wasn't seeing. I appreciate the second set of eyes :)